# Access sub-process controlling terminal from Java process

Tags: java, linux, terminal, tty

I have a long-running Java server application that launches a sub-process to perform a particular task (in this case, extract the contents of a 7zip file using the `7z` command-line utility, but that particular detail shouldn't be relevant here).

- The server application runs with Java 8 under Ubuntu 14.
- The sub-process is being launched via the Java [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) API.
- The file being accessed by the sub-process might be password-protected.
- If the file is password-protected and no password is supplied as a command-line argument, the `7z` program will attempt to display a message to the terminal prompting for a password, and then read the password from the terminal.
- At this point, the sub-process hangs and will not complete unless I hit `<Enter>` twice in the terminal that controls the Java process.

The underlying issue seems to be that the `7z` utility uses the [getpass](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpass.3.html) system call to display the prompt and read user input. According to the docs:

> The getpass() function opens /dev/tty (the controlling terminal of the process), outputs the string prompt, turns off echoing, reads one line (the "password"), restores the terminal state and closes /dev/tty again.

Since this is a server application, it is not acceptable to have the sub-process block waiting on input from the Java terminal. What I would like to happen instead is to programmatically shut down input on the sub-process terminal, so that the `getpass` call returns immediately with no input and the sub-process exits with an error code. Unfortunately all of my attempts at shutting down input to the sub-process terminal have resulted in the same behavior as above:

- I tried manually closing the stream returned by [`Process.getOutputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--) immediately after starting the sub-process.
- I tried using [`ProcessBuilder.redirectInput`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectInput-java.io.File-) to redirect sub-process input to read from an empty file, and from `/dev/null`.
- For good measure, I even tried passing `Redirect.INHERIT` to ProcessBuilder even though that doesn't seem like it's remotely what I want.

It seems like this *should* be feasible, because I've observed the desired behavior when `7z` is launched with the exact same command-line as a sub-process of a daemonized `socat` process where the terminal input is connected to `/dev/null`, but I'm at a loss for how to accomplish this in Java using the tools at my disposal.

Comment: As far as I know  there is no way to manage sub-process in Java 8. Extended process API comes with Java 9.

Comment: @LEQADA Unfortunately, from skimming the updated Java 9 API docs, I don't see anything immediately obvious that would help me here.

Answer (score 0):

In order to preclude that the *getpass() function opens /dev/tty (the controlling terminal of the process)*, we have to arrange that the utility has no controlling tty, which is achieved by calling [setsid()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid). This C program (let's name it `notty`) makes this call and then executes the given utility:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setsid();                   // get rid of the controlling tty
    close(0);                   // preclude reading STDIN as well
    execvp(argv[1], argv+1);    // execute the given program file
}
```

We can use it from the Java application by prepending it to the ProcessBuilder command, e. g.:

```
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("notty", "7z", … /*arguments*/);
```